# what middlewares do I need for a http web server in node.js?

Tags: node.js

First of all, I know that there are some great frameworks like express.js for node.js lovers.

But when I decide to use Koa, I know that I do not know what middlewares I need
for building a simple http web server and even if I could search some middlewares from great examples using koa, there remains some confuses about what middleware should I put first second and...

In sight of newbie, I need some middlewares to

send a static file, (koa-static)

log something, (koa-logger)

cache files, (koa-static-cache)

routes, (koa-route)

and anything else?

and how to order those middlewares?

The concept that running downstream middlewares and yielding upstream middlewares is awesome to me, but I cannot decide orders for my ignorance.

Hope that not very stupid question.
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you may need middleware some of the following :

- parsing the request
- handling errors
- keeping a server-side session
- CORS
- authentication (oauth etc.)
- authorization
- performance monitoring
- context injection (e.g attach your database connections and environment variables to your request)
- 'data injection' (e.g the model of currently logged in user)

As for the ordering, I think a lot of permutations are possible, you should just try to state dependencies between your middleware (e.g middleware X should be after middleware Y) and account for them in your ordering. For example, if you don't want to log file calls, the logging middleware should be after the static files middleware.

Comment: thanks for details and kindness. These lists would be very helpful for me and nodejs newbies. thanks :)